# HttpClient call not triggering sometimes

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient, angular-httpclient

I have an angular application with a component that loads a form when a user goes to a page.
on that form component, i am trying to get a dropdown list populated from the backend using http get call. The function to call backend is triggered on ngOnInit.

```
ngOnInit() {

// initiating form
this.AddUserForm();

// function to call backend to populate dropdown list
this.getGroups();

}
```

and the "getGroups" function is like below

```
getGroups() {
    console.log("fetching groups")

    this.http.get<Array<String>>(environment.getGroups)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log("retrieved data for groups")
      this.myGroups = data
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error occured while getting groups")
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

This works in development but in prod, the HTTP call doesn't get triggered sometimes only.
The `console.log("fetching groups")` works every time but the actual call doesn't get triggered and it doesn't error out too.

Any ideas, what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There should be a problem with API endpoint. Just double check API end point..

Comment: Are you seeing any requests in the network tab of your developer console?

Comment: @micronyks Thanks for the suggestion. i checked the endpoint it looks good.

Comment: @FrancoisduPlessis Thanks for the tip, I looked up in the network tab and I found out that the request was being queued and stalled for a long time. It did get processed eventually after a minute. Any idea how I can move it up the queue?

Comment: @TRenold I'm not exactly sure what you mean by queue, but I've got a suspicion that it might be that your API is taking long to react to a request. What happens if you make the same exact request from something like curl or postman, do you still experience the same delay?

Comment: @FrancoisduPlessis If I go to the network tab of dev. console in chrome, I can see the network call is in "cancelled" state, so the request was never made to the backend. 
This is an intermittent issue and I am unable to put a pin on why is it happening.

Comment: @TRenold and you only experience this when the call is made from your angular app? Manual requests to the API all resolve quickly?